# How to make my app stay login even after power-off on ipad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, authentication, nsuserdefaults

I created a web service application. I want my user to allways stay login after installition but i have no idea about how to do this. I save user informations in NSUserDefaults. Thank in Advance

**EDIT** I log into the server, user informations are firstly created on server and i sen Username&Password ect via a GET to the server. If this data sent in GET are the same with ones in server, the user will login into the application. Anything(content) of application comes from server after logging in.

Comment: can you clarify, logged in where. on the web server or the device. and what do you really mean by logged in?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *savedUserName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userName"];
NSString *savedUserPass = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userPass"];

if (savedUserName && savedUserPass){ // check for length as well
  //don't show login, create user with these credentials
}
else{
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"newUserName" forKey:@"userName"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"newUserPass" forKey:@"userPass"];
  //then show login for logging in as a new user
}
```

Don't forget to save nil or empty string when user logs out.

Comment: I have used exactly this, no matter with saving user informations. But whenever i close the Simulator and restart, it asks user informations. But what i want is, whenever after installition i start the app, to be started with the application's main page, not the user login page

Comment: What do you mean _after installition_? If you delete app from Simulator, then all data including user defaults with saved pass and username will be deleted as well. It's a common behavior for iOS, you cann't change it. And when you install new version, then this one will not has any saved data.

Comment: By installition i mean installing the app on the simulator, not installing the Simulator. For example, i open the simulator, enter my user informations, later reset the simulator, in this point i'm asked to re-enter the informations. But i want the user infos to stay there.

Comment: If you reset the simulator, all the data related to that app is gone.

Comment: You mean, if i test this on my ipad i won't have any problem?

Comment: The Keychain is a better place to put User name and password information.

Comment: @Abizern It is safe if I want to save only the login "status" and no other information using NSUserDefault and no keychan? I think using keychain for that it's too much.